# Creating a table in HTML

Tags: html, css

To create table in [HTML](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTML) we use <table>, <tr>, <th>, and <td>.

But nowadays I see often <thead>, <tfoot>, and <tbody>` used. Is this a new method of HTML? Why is this needed too? What are the benefits of doing it like this?

Comment: A simple google search will answer your question

Comment: I have http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_tbody.asp this but din't understand properly. I mean why to use this instead?

Comment: I suggest you to always refer to [W3C](http://www.w3.org/html/) rearding HTML specification. Many would strongly desagree in consulting [w3schools](http://w3fools.com/). In general, before posting, have a look to the [tag info](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/html/info).

Comment: w3schools has nice tutorial and why disagree consulting this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Refer to *[HTML <thead> Tag](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_thead.asp)*. It gives the browser more information about the table, allowing it to make smarter choices when displaying the table.

For example: When scrolling in a big table, the header might be locked to the top of the screen, so you do not need to scroll up to find out what a column meant.

Answer (score 1):

Theey are just new tags used to specify each part of a table (body, header, and footer). Before it was possible only with the `<th>` tag (header).

It might be easier to style these elements with [CSS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cascading_Style_Sheets) too.

Answer (score 1):

First you should know that HTML has already been upgraded to [HTML5](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTML5). So previously HTML tags didn't have the tags such as you mentioned so <thead> is for the table header, <tfoot> for the footer and <tbody> is the same as body when you are starting a HTML page.

For more information, better go to *[HTML5 Demos and Examples](http://html5demos.com/)*.

Answer (score 1):

It is just an advanced way of writing [HTML](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTML) table tags (body, head, and footer).